# Testing the significance of preference in product selection (count data)

Tags: statistical-significance, count-data

In an experiment, I am asking people to choose between two products (A or B), for several pairs P. For some pairs, there's a strong preference, for others there isn't. The data looks like this (N=20):

```
_    A    B
P1   8   12
P2   13   7
P3   10  10
P4   11  9
```

For example, 8 customers chose product A and not product B in pair P1.
How do I test the statistical significance of these differences over a set of item pairs **for each pair**? I know that there are significant differences between pairs, but I would like to measure the significance of the choice in each pair.

Essentially I want some measure to assess whether these are just random variations. Another option would be to find a way to compare pairs P.

Comment: What do the numbers in the "A" and "B" columns mean?  If we are to treat them purely as numbers, then this question has been asked and answered many times: use an appropriate test of a location difference for paired variables.

Comment: I added an explanation.